# ggplot with missing values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset like this

```
data <- data.frame(Time=as.Date(c("2007-01-31", "2007-02-28", "2007-03-31", "2007-04-30", 
        "2007-05-31", "2007-06-30", "2007-07-31", "2007-08-31", "2007-09-30", "2007-10-31", 
        "2007-11-30", "2007-12-31"), format="%Y-%m-%d"), 
        a=c(NA, NA, 1.201, NA, NA, 1.206, NA, NA, 1.212, NA, NA, 1.237), 
        b=c(1.187, 1.201, 1.206, 1.219, 1.211, 1.187, 1.202, 1.213, 1.209, 1.208, 
          1.219, 1.237), 
        c=c(1.198, 1.201, 1.203, 1.206, 1.207,1.207, 1.208, 1.21, 1.214, 1.22, 1.228, 1.236))
> data
     Time     a     b     c
1  2007-01-31    NA 1.187 1.198
2  2007-02-28    NA 1.201 1.201
3  2007-03-31 1.201 1.206 1.203
4  2007-04-30    NA 1.219 1.206
5  2007-05-31    NA 1.211 1.207
6  2007-06-30 1.206 1.187 1.207
7  2007-07-31    NA 1.202 1.208
8  2007-08-31    NA 1.213 1.210
9  2007-09-30 1.207 1.209 1.214
10 2007-10-31    NA 1.208 1.220
11 2007-11-30    NA 1.219 1.228
12 2007-12-31 1.219 1.237 1.236
```

I want a ggplot with points for a and lines for b & c. I came up with

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Time)) +  geom_point(aes(y=a, colour="a"), size=3) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=b, colour="b")) + geom_line(aes(y=c, colour="c"))
```

The problem is, that I have many more variables like b & c, which I want to plot. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: you could reshape your data, like so: `library(tidyr);library(dplyr); gather(data, Var, Val) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Val, color = Var, group = Var)) + geom_line()`

Comment: use `melt` from `reshape2` package to melt all the line related variables. You will get a `variable` column which can be used to group and line type and a column called `value` which can be used to print the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both methods to reshape my data, gather() and melt(), work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is with the tidyr package (and some dplyr)

```
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')
data2 <- gather(data, grp, value, a:c)
ggplot(data2, aes(x = Time, y = value, color = grp, group = grp)) +  
  geom_point(data = filter(data2, grp == 'a'), size = 3) + 
  geom_line()
```

The plot
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I need.